# wordpress edit right-bar div on trim theme

Tags: html, wordpress

I've recently been handed a website to update with new information for my school. It's using wordpress with the "trim" theme form elegant themes. The front page of the site is configured to show latest posts instead of a static page. The site is [ideacharterschool.com](http://ideacharterschool.com/). The news section is pretty self explanatory, it updates from posts in the news category. But I can't figure out how to edit everything on the right side of the page, in the "right-side" div.

[(Area I'm talking about)](http://i.imgur.com/6kZ5UfH.png)

Any ideas on how to edit this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what's in right-side are widgets in a sidebar. In that case, go to Appearance > Widgets and find the right-side sidebar.